# Form inserting a blank row into the data table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am quite new to this and this problem has been on my back for a few days now.
I have searched for answers to my problem but couldn't find anything satisfying for what I need.
I am trying to send some data through a form into a database and then represent the respective data into a table that shows specific rows.
My problem is that one of those rows (the Actions row) appears stored as blank data eventhough the user fills the form with something...anything.

This is my Add.php file:

```
<?php

$name="";$first="";$last="";$email="";$pass="";$acti="";

mysql_connect("localhost","admin") or die (mysqli_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("test") or die (mysql_error());

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","","test")or die (mysqli_error());
if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $first=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']);
    $last=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last']);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    if(isset($_POST['acti']){$actions=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acti']);}

    echo "A new record has been added!";

$query="INSERT INTO users (Name,FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,Actions) 
VALUES ('$name','$first','$last','$email','$pass','$acti')";
$result=mysql_query($query)
            or die (mysql_error()); 

}


mysqli_close($con);

?>
//the form is included in the file
<html>
<head>
    <body>
    <br/><br/><h2 align=center ><b> Registration page </b></h2><br/><br/><br/>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" align=center >
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"> <br/>
First Name:<input name="first" input type="text" value="<?php echo $first;?>"> <br/>
Last Name:<input name="last" input type="text" value="<?php echo $last;?>"> <br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"> <br/>
Password:<input type="password" input name="pass" value="<?php echo $pass;?>"> <br/>
Actions:<input name="action" input type="text" value="<?php echo $acti;?>"><br/<br/>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
</form>
<p align=center>Click <a href="List.php"> here</a> for a list!</p>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

And this is my List.php file:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","admin") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die (mysql_error());
/*mysql_query("CREATE TABLE users(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (id),Name VARCHAR(255),FirstName VARCHAR(255),LastName VARCHAR(255),Email VARCHAR(255),Password VARCHAR(255),Actions VARCHAR(255))") or die (mysql_error());*/

echo"<table border='2' align=center>";
echo"<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Actions</th> </tr>";
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr> <td>";
        echo $row['Name'];
        echo"</td> <td>";
        echo $row['Email'];
        echo"</td> <td>";
        echo $row['Actions'];
        echo"</td> </tr>";

    }
echo"</table>";
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` up. Do not do this! PLEASE go with `mysqli_*` and learn how to do prepared statements.

Comment: just to clarify why you should be using mysqli_* this is because it is improved and if I remember correctly mysql_* is now unsupported and no longer maintained

Comment: just to add another point you really need to use MVC (Model View Controller).PHP inside your html is pretty bad.

Comment: @OliverBS to be precise `mysql_*` deprecated from `php 5.5`

Comment: You are connecting to DB two times. first with mysql_connect and next with mysqli_connect

Comment: @krishna thanks for that :) always nice to see people doing the correct research and not guessing :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `$_POST['acti'];` when the field name is `name='action'`.

You've put:

```
if(isset($_POST['acti']){$actions=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acti']);}
                  ^ acti                                            ^acti
```

Your HTML:

```
Actions:<input name="action" input type="text" value="<?php echo $acti;?>"><br/<br/>
                       ^action, not 'acti'
```

Either use `name='acti'` in your form, or `$_POST['action']` in your PHP.

Please look at [this link](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) on how to use `mysqli` properly.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing between mysql and mysqli

switch all mysql codes to mysqli example:

```
 $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

should be

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

this

```
 $result=mysql_query($query)
        or die (mysql_error());
```

should be

```
$result=mysqli_query($query)
        or die (mysqli_error());
```

this

```
 if(isset($_POST['acti'])
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])
```

BTW: you connecting by two methodes ?? mysql and mysqli ??

remove this:

```
 mysql_connect("localhost","admin") or die (mysqli_error());//this connection is mysql and is also wrong without password.
 $db=mysql_select_db("test") or die (mysql_error());
```

and connect only by mysqli.

Comment: Although this is true, it's `action` that he's not getting (because he's calling `acti` not `action`. But this could have been a comment, and someone of your rep should really now that.

Comment: @echo_Me `mysqli_error()` expect parameter, which should `$con` here

Comment: dude its almost all your code is wrong with connection , try rewrite your code with only mysqli.